# How to group posted array names by index in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am currently working on a project where the fields scale when clicking on the "Add" button.
I am grouping each field like this: `name="packaging[]"`, `name="packaging[1]"`, `name="packaging[2]"` and so on. When I submit the form, this is how the data looks like when posted:

```
Array
(
    [packaging] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [quantity] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [total-weight] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [length] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

)
```

Using PHP I would like to convert the above code to look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [packaging] => 1,
            [quantity] => 1,
            [total-weight] => 1,
            [length] => 1,
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [packaging] => 2,
            [quantity] => 2,
            [total-weight] => 2,
            [length] => 2,
        )
)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this....

```
$array=array();
foreach($data as $key=>$value){
    foreach($value as $k=>$val){
         $array[$k][$key]=$val;
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://phpio.net/s/ujp)

Comment: There could be more than two rows submitted. How can I make your code scalable?

Comment: Why is it this is not the best answer? Hmm, this is the cleanest, scalable answer for me.

Comment: Yes I agree, @Nikhil Vaghela's changes came in kinda late which I did not see earlier. It is now marked as the best answer. Thank you so much guys!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
  $rows = array ('packaging' => array ('0'=> 1,'1' => 2),'quantity' => array('0'=> 1,'1' => 2),'total-weight' => array ('0'=> 1,'1' => 2),
'length' =>array ('0'=> 1,'1' => 2)

 );
  $res_array = array();
  $total_records = count($rows['packaging']);
 for($i=0;$i<$total_records;$i++)
 {
     $res_array[] = array('packaging'=>$rows['packaging']   [$i],'quantity'=>$rows['quantity'][$i],
    'total-weight'=>$rows['total-weight'][$i],'length'=>$rows['length'] [$i]);
 }
print_r($res_array);
```

Comment: There could be more than two rows submitted. How can I make your code scalable?

Comment: If there is 3 rows, then there will be 3 elements in each sub_array right?. in that case this code will work. For loop will loop upto number of elements in each sub_array